# Flutter Blank(White) is showing if app kept in background for long time

Tags: android, flutter

We have added Flutter in the existing native app. normally its workoing fine, but Flutter screen is blank(white) screen when the app is in the background for a long time about 15 min or more that means when I resuming the app after some time it is showing a blank screen. As shown in below screenshot,`DAV SANDBOX PROD` is in android native, upper part is in Flutter its blank [image]

Comment: Does it matter what screen you are on in the app, or is this a particular type of view e.g a webview?

Comment: Also is this in debug mode or production?

Comment: yes it's for all and it does not matter the type of view, if the app is in the background for a long time  we face the issue

Comment: Can you go into debug mode a replicate the issue, pay attention to any errors that appear in the debug console.

Comment: checked the logs but not got any information

Comment: I saw you posted on the github issue page too, can you add your 'flutter doctor -v' output.

Comment: yes added .....

Comment: Has anyone had any luck in fixing this issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the issue your facing

Comment: I am facing with the same issue. Did you resolve it?